# Android Jetpack Compose Room query with body

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-jetpack-compose

i try to do the following:

```
@Query("SELECT COUNT(s_row) FROM table WHERE data = :data")
fun isDataExist(data: String): Boolean{
    if (*QUERY_RETURN*) > 0{
    return true
    } else {
    return false
    }
}
```

so my question is is there a way to have a body to test the query return and then return a boolean if the data already exist in the database?

Comment: For now the only way i saw is in my viewmodel add a isDataExist fun that will return true or false based on the dao return

Answer (score 1):

For the starters `dao` is `interface` and you should not implement its methods.

```
@Dao
interface DataDao {

//dao function should not have a body
 @Query("SELECT * FROM some_table")
 suspend fun selectFunction():List<String>

//dao function should not have a body
@Query("DELETE FROM some_table")
 suspend fun clearData() .... }
```

You just write the queries, ROOM has underlying logic to do the rest.

In your case what you can do is to use an **identifier** or an ***id*** to query if the item exists in the database.

You can do something like this - note this is a `suspend` function as this is a database operation.

```
@Query("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table_name WHERE id=:id)")
suspend fun isDataExist(id: String): Boolean
```

Afterwards you can use this function in a repository implementation or ViewModel (using ViemodelScope)

Comment: Hello, i'll try that and give you feedback, i knew i was doing something wrong, but wasn'T sure how to did it right

Comment: After giving it a try i got the following error:
```
Query method parameters should either be a type that can be converted into a database column or a List / Array that contains such type. You can consider adding a Type Adapter for this.```

Edit: if i remove the suspend everything work, i think the suspend must nut be in the dao but in the function that call the DAO